# Xcode 7 Tests don't run but reports success

Tags: unit-testing, xcode7, xctest

I'm trying to add a test target to my project, however When I run the tests it seems like the actual tests aren't being executed, instead Xcode reports success always, but the small square which indicates if the test passed or not remains clear.

I only have one test target and one class:

```
@implementation Tests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

- (void)tearDown {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testExample {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    XCTAssert(false, "");
}

- (void)testPerformanceExample {
    XCTAssert(false, "");
}

@end
```

The test should fail but it displays a popup saying success. Also, the test report says there are no tests.

If I try to run the tests individually the tests "succeed" but I get no information on the report and the square remains empty.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?? I am too getting the same issue

Comment: Sorry.. It went away with the XCode update

Comment: i had similar problem: wouldn't run tests, didn't report anything, brief heads-up display said tests _failed_. rebooting device fixed it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are building for iOS do you usually have Xcode set to run on a physical device? If so try setting it to run on the iOS simulator.

I found that if you have Xcode 7 set to on a physical device unit testing will behave exactly as you've described. Setting Xcode to run on the iOS simulator temporarily for unit testing fixed the problem right up, and now it works like a charm.

I hope this helps anyone running into the same problem. :D

Comment: so you just run tests on simulator, passed, then on device and it worked? if so it's still not working for me :/ usually resetting phone and/or Xcode and/or deleting derived data helps

Comment: @raistlin Yes, that is what I did. If you're still having the issue after trying all of the options you mentioned then try taking a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233626/xcode-5-says-tests-failed-but-shows-green-checkmarks). The user ReDetection mentioned he had to "reset the iPhone Simulator contents and Settings" from the simulator's menus, and then tried what I mentioned.

Answer (score 41):

For anyone else facing this issue, check to make sure that your test class is inheriting from XCTestCase as opposed to XCTest. I was going crazy trying all of these solutions until I realized that I was inheriting from the wrong class. Xcode doesn't complain, it will simply say tests succeeded without running them. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Right on point! I was inheriting from XCTest and was going around scratching my head as to what was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: This was my issue as well! Thank you so much for posting that answer!

Comment: I could not get my head around why and fortunately I ran into this comment!

Answer (score 23):

Worth mentioning that Xcode only runs XCTestCase functions that start with 'test'. This is contrary to other platforms, and confused me when I started testing with Xcode.

The reason for this is so that you can have some convenient helpful methods inside you test classes which you don't necessarily want to call as tests themselves.

In the following test class:

```swift
class MyBigTest: XCTestCase {

    func testSensibleInputReturnSensibleAnswer() {
        XCTAssert(/* stuff */)
    }

    func setupSomeKindOfData() {
        // does some data setup here
    }

}
```

Only `testSensibleInputReturnSensibleAnswer()` will be called by the test suite. The `setupSomeKindOfData()` function may have some shared setup logic that lots of test functions will call.

Additionally, some people like to format their test method names with `_`s to make them more readable. For example: `test_sensibleAnswer_sensibleResult()`.

Answer (score 10):

Power Off the iOS device and then power back on.  You may also want to remove the USB cable and reconnect so that Xcode can reestablish communications with the device.  When this happened to me the test would report test succeeded immediately without the test ever being run.  I also noticed that when I tried to record a new UI test action that Xcode crashed every time - similar to the way it behaved before I first enabled the iOS Settings - Developer - Enable UI Automation setting and I remembered that an iOS device restart was necessary when this was enabled so I tried the iOS device restart and Xcode started behaving again where I could record and run tests successfully against my iOS devices.  Full Disclosure: I also toggled the Enable UI Automation on and off before I rebooted my iOS device but I doubt that was required. -rrh

Comment: actually enabling UI Automation and rebooting device helped me

Answer (score 10):

Check the console (Command-Shift-Y).

In my case there was output being printed indicating why the tests were not running. (pre-flight check for dynamic frameworks was failing.) But I didn't see it because the debug area was collapsed.

Also in my case the issue was fixed by adding `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS` to my runtime search paths as described [here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1002)

Comment: was my problem too. Thanks alot. This was surprisingly hard to find.

Comment: With me the problem was that i forgot to unlink frameworks, which i deleted previously, from test module. Thanks for reminding me of the console :D

Comment: +1 for not seeing the debug area. It just stayed closed for me, so I just assumed there was nothing there to see.

Answer (score 7):

I had the test method marked as `private` and what solved it for me was simply removing the `private` access modifier.

Comment: This was that only thing that helped me - Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and cleaning the build folder would solve it. However, there's an even faster way which is doing `Product -> Perform Action -> Test Without Building`

Answer (score 3):

Old question but the things that solved it in my case was mentioned here yet:

You cannot (always?) rename test classes / cases. Create a new class / case and throw away the old one.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for UI automation testing then might be because you are not initializing the application and launching it.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app launch];
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I also had a very similar issue when using KIF's `beforeAll`. Sometimes the code placed inside `beforeAll` just didn't work and still the test would return as success.

It also sometimes makes Xcode crash. See KIF's Github page [here](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/905#issuecomment-245061529). Though some have pointed out that the issue may not be because of KIF and rather because of XCTest itself

The temporary solution was to avoid using `beforeAll` and instead use `beforeEach`

Answer (score 0):

I run into this situation when created `Objective-C` test **class** with the same name as existing `Swift` class.

Just rename a test file