# Xcode 7 test fails but shows successful

Tags: ios, xcode, kiwi

I am not sure if I am making a mistake or there is a bug.

I have setup 2 tests. One of them fails one doesn't but the test suit gets the checkmark.

it seems like there has been a similar issue before in Xcode 5 but this was not useful to me.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233626/xcode-5-says-tests-failed-but-shows-green-checkmarks](https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Kiwi-2.0)

[This is what I followed to setup kiwi](https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Kiwi-2.0)

I appreciate the help.[image]